# Doctrine prevent object deletion

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project I have two entities: ***planifications*** and ***selections***.

There is a relation between these two objects: A planification **MUST** contain **ONE** selection. The same selection can be used by multiple planifications.

The generated code looks like this:

```
// Planification.php - class Planification

  /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Selection", inversedBy="planifications")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="selection_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
  private $selection;


// Selection.php - class Selection

  /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Planification", mappedBy="selection")
    */
  private $planifications;
```

What I would like to do is not allow a selection to be deleted if it is referenced by a planification. In other words, if a planification contains a selection - that selection can not be deleted. What happens to me is if I try to delete a selection that is in a planification, the operation completes successfully, and the `$selection` member in the `Planification` class contains `NULL`.

Would fixing this be possible in doctrine? I have tried adding `nullable=false` (on the `$selection` member) and `onDelete="NO ACTION"`, and both solutions don't work.

Comment: Have you got a FOREIGN KEY on selection_id in your table ? This foreign key should have been generated by doctrine. If the foreign key is present, you should not be able to delete a selection that is referenced by a planification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the `make:entity` command when creating it so I left all of the code generation up to doctrine. It's possible that I forgot to mark it as non nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Doctrine annotation to disallow `Planification::$selection` to be null, would be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Selection", inversedBy="planifications")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="selection_id", nullable=false)
 */
  private $selection;
```

(You do not need the `referencedColumnName` setting, since it defaults to `id`, and `nullable=false` goes in the `@JoinColumn` annotation).

Having the annotation will not update the DB to fit this particular definition.

Execute `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see the needed SQL to update your table definition, and run the resultant appropriate SQL statements against your DB to update the DB schema.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the answer. The `nullable=false` part was correct, I just forgot to execute `doctrine:schema:update --force`